# Excel 2007 - Changing Pivot Filter with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have multiple Pivottables in Excel. Using a Control Sheet I want to be able to change the Filter of all Pivot tables by pressing a button. So, in the end, there should be one button for "Remove all Filters" and one button for "Set Filters". "Set Filters" should then set a "multiple filter" (i.e. just show category 1, 2 and 3, not 4 and 5) on PivotTable1, PivotTable2 and PivotTable3.

I know how to add buttons and how to assign code to them, but I dont really know how to approach this in VBA - any ideas?

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 0):

Normal when I know how to do something in Excel but not VBA, I will record a macro doing the task and then look at the code generated by the macro.   You could record two macros one to set and the other to unset the filters.  You can then copy the code for your buttons or call the macros directly.